# Expand Collapse Menu in JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this code to make a menu that collapses when the user clicks on the minus sign within a page. But the menu shows all the contents within the Main Item when the page first loads. I would like to make the page show just the Main Item when the page loads. This is the code:

```
    <script langauge="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function doMenu(item) {
 obj=document.getElementById(item);
 col=document.getElementById("x" + item);
 if (obj.style.display=="none") {
  obj.style.display="block";
  col.innerHTML="[-]";
 }
 else {
  obj.style.display="none";
  col.innerHTML="[+]";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="JavaScript:doMenu('main');" id=xmain>[+]</a> Main Item
<div id=main style="margin-left:1em">
 <a href=#>Item 1</a><br>
 <a href=#>Item 2</a><br>
 <a href=#>Item 3</a>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to change the code to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<a href="JavaScript:doMenu('main');" id=xmain>
```

to:

```
<a href="JavaScript:doMenu('main');" style="display: none;" id=xmain>
```

BTW, as some side notes the code you found is not very good. If this is intended as a professional project I wouldn't use it.

For one, I would change:

```
obj.style.display="block";
```

to:

```
obj.style.display="";
```

To avoid some bugs in certain browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that changing

```
<div id=main style="margin-left:1em">
```

to

```
<div id=main style="margin-left:1em; display:none">
```

should work.